# GTK_IS_WIDGET(WIDGET) failed

Tags: c, gtk, codeblocks, glade

I am currently trying to learn how to use GTK with C on a Windows 7 computer. I suppose that is my first problem I'm running in to.

I am following a tutorial series located here: http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html#Manipulating_Widget_Properties

Following all of the steps, I get to the point where I compile. The program compiles fine and when I run it, I get the GTK_IS_WIDGET(WIDGET) error. Upon investigation of this function, it seems to be that the most common error is a mismatch between the name of your topmost window in the Glade design, and the call in the function. I renamed both the window and call to just normal "window" and I get the same error.

Upon debugging the code,

```
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "tutorial.xml", NULL);
window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
```

This line appears to be what I believe to be the line in question. window gets set to null after this line and I'm assuming that is where the issue comes from.

Double checking everything, my top most window is still named "window" and the tutorial file is spelled correctly and called "tutorial.glade"

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: My first question is why you are trying to develop gtk on a non-native operating system.

Comment: Found out my own answer. I was saving in an incorrect way. Saved it as a libglade rather than a gtkbuilder.

Comment: @ciphermagi basic/mediocre stuff should work quite well across all platforms. And for the bunch of issues remaining there is  bugzilla.gnome.org to report actual issues and see if there are workarounds or fixes in git.